# Problems combining tensorflow with huggingGPT transformers on a python project

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

This is my code:

```
mport os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from database import create_connection
import mysql.connector
# from user_interface import user_interface
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertForSequenceClassification
import tensorflow as tf



# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

print(tf.__version__)

app = Flask(__name__)

# Get environment variables
host = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
user = os.getenv('DB_USER')
password = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
db_name = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

connection = create_connection(host, user, password, db_name)

# Load the model and tokenizer
# model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Define categories
```

but when I try to run I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1076, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_tf_bert.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ...modeling_tf_utils import (
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 70, in <module>
    from keras.engine import data_adapter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pedrospecter/Downloads/work/cw1/autonomous_ai/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertForSequenceClassification
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1231, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1067, in __getattr__
    value = getattr(module, name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1066, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1078, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.bert.modeling_tf_bert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'keras.engine'
```

I have installed both transformers and tensorflow using:

```
pip3 install transformers tensorflow
```

I am on a MacBook Pro M2 Max

does anyone have a tip on how can I run this? The code is just the essential until the error shows up, but there is way more code under.

Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [huggingface transformers RuntimeError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras\_tensor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70791672/huggingface-transformers-runtimeerror-no-module-named-tensorflow-python-keras)

Comment: Looks kind of clear to me how to debug your problem `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine'`

Comment: which tensorflow version do you have? https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/3658488ff77ff8d45101293e749263acf437f4d5/src/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py#L68-L77

Comment: TF - 2.13.0.rc1, keras is also installed. @Iván

Comment: Can you confirm that you can run this without errors `from keras.engine import data_adapter`

Comment: And also which version of keras do you have?

Comment: Okay finally that was useful but still not solving the problem. from keras.engine import data_adapter - did not recognised the module. (obvious). But keras 2.13.1.rc0 is installed. When I tried to uninstall it, and downgrade it to 2.12.0 then tensorflow does not work because it requires 2.13.0.rc1 (and supposedly installs it)

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow reinstalls keras 2.13

Comment: you are using a rc, thats a release candidate, maybe it is better to stick to 2.12 which is the latest stable version. Also instead of using brew python installation I recommend you using conda and some virtual env to avoid breaking all your python every time you are changing something.

Comment: I installed the 2.12 and solved it (Big thanks), but then I got this: TFBertForSequenceClassification requires the TensorFlow library but it was not found in your environment.
@Iván

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the latest stable version and not a release candidate. In this case install tf and keras 2.12.

Also I don't recommend using brew python. Install `conda` and create a virtual env to experiment with installations there if you are not very experienced with packages and versions.

Final the error that you mention `TFBertForSequenceClassification requires the TensorFlow library but it was not found in your environment` can be easily [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624869/tfbertforsequenceclassification-requires-the-tensorflow-library-but-it-was-not-f). Google is your friend.

So to wrap up.

1. Install conda
2. Setup a virtual env
3. Install everything in that virtual env (make sure to activate it before).
4. Install stuff with conda and not with pip (recommendation not mandatory).
5. Make sure you are using gpu tf,  `pip install tensorflow-gpu` for example (the last error is related to this). Conda handles quite good gpu support.

[Conda, getting started](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)