# TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM requires the TensorFlow library but it was not found in your environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

For code below:

```
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline
# Load the pre-trained T5 model and tokenizer
model_checkpoint = "t5-small"
model = TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)

# Define the summarization function


summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, framework="tf")

summarizer(
   "how are you today? this is something remarkable, the sun is from the west",
    min_length=1,
    max_length=19,
)
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_37988/4253040799.py in <module>
      3 # Load the pre-trained T5 model and tokenizer
      4 model_checkpoint = "t5-small"
----> 5 model = TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
      6 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
      7 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\dummy_tf_objects.py in from_pretrained(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    262     @classmethod
    263     def from_pretrained(cls, *args, **kwargs):
--> 264         requires_backends(cls, ["tf"])
    265 
    266 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\file_utils.py in requires_backends(obj, backends)
    681     name = obj.__name__ if hasattr(obj, "__name__") else obj.__class__.__name__
    682     if not all(BACKENDS_MAPPING[backend][0]() for backend in backends):
--> 683         raise ImportError("".join([BACKENDS_MAPPING[backend][1].format(name) for backend in backends]))
    684 
    685 

ImportError: 
TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM requires the TensorFlow library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page: https://www.tensorflow.org/install and follow the ones that match your environment.
```

How should I solve it?

The result of pip list show that I have tensorflow 2.12.0 installed

```
tensorflow                         2.12.0
```

I have seen this [TFBertForSequenceClassification requires the TensorFlow library but it was not found in your environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624869/tfbertforsequenceclassification-requires-the-tensorflow-library-but-it-was-not-f) but neither solution within help.

Update for Alvas:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before this:

```
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline
```

Try this:

```
import tensorflow

from transformers import TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline
```

Most probably the `ImportError` will be raised in the first line.

If so, then your default `pip` on command line may not be the same as the one in your Jupyter notebook. To check, do this inside the Jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

And you will see something like

```
'/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3'
```

Then inside the Jupyter notebook, do:

```
! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 pip install -U tensorflow
```

---

Alternatively, from the looks of the traceback, you seem to be using Anaconda, might be able to resolve the import errors, by using conda instead on the CLI before you call `jupyter notebook` or `jupyterlab`

```
conda install tensorflow
```

See https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment

---

Alternatively, if you are using Anaconda, and you know that your path to Python is this:

```
/Users/william007/anaconda/bin/python
```

Then you can also do:

```
! /Users/william007/anaconda/bin/python -m pip install -U tensorflow
```

See https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/configurations/python-path/

Comment: Yes `import tensorflow` give error, and using your instruction does not work as attached at the end of my question.

Comment: Because it's a windows, try the `! conda install -U tensorflow`